# Android changes color of pixels while decoding an Image

Tags: android, image, colors, drawable

I have a .png Image that I ant to load into my App. It is a shape which is colored in a specific color, so that every pixel has exactly the same RGB-Value. The only difference is the alpha value, which decreases at the edges of the shape.

My problem is, that if I load the image with `BitmapFactory.decodeResource()` the pixels on the edge get another RGB-Value. It's not a big change, it's just -+4 red/green/blue value, but for me it is a big change, because the pixels have to be this exact color.

I want to mask them out and replace them with another color. This specific color is my indicator, so that I find the pixels I want to change. If I change the color the edge is still colored differently and thats annoying.

Is there a way to load Drawables without them being changed?

Answer (score 0):

You should try using this variant:

```
decodeResource(Resources res, int id, BitmapFactory.Options opts)
```

with configured opts. Play with its params **inPreferredColorSpace**,**outColorSpace** and **inPreferredConfig**,**outConfig**

Comment: Sorry, but that doesn't change anything. And the inPreferredColorSpace has a too high API anyway.